# Quotienting a virtually cyclic group by an element

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $K$ be a group, $G \unlhd K$ be a finite normal subgroup of even order, and let $\langle h \rangle<K$ be an infinite cyclic subgroup, so that they fit into a short exact sequence $$0\to G\to K \to \langle h \rangle \to 0.$$

Question: when can $K$ modulo the normal subgroup generated by $\langle h \rangle$ be trivial?

Comment: Does "$K/(h)$ trivial" implies K is infinite cyclic? If it's true, how could $G<K$ be normal?

Comment: (h) is a cyclic subgroup of K. I asked when K/H, where H is the normal subgroup generated by (h), is trivial.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of making the title more descriptive. Please feel free to edit as you please, but something much more speicific than the original title would be preferable.

Comment: Yes. There are easy examples. (1) Take $G$ simple non-abelian and any non-trivial action for the semidirect product. (2) Take $G$ abelian of odd order and $h$ acting on $G$ by $x\mapsto -x$. Etc. In general let $u$ be the automorphism of $G$ induced by $h$. Then the required property holds iff the normal subgroup of $G$ generated by $\{g^{-1}u(g):g\in G\}$ is $G$ itself.

Comment: The problem I always have with this type of question is that I have no idea what sort of answer the poster is looking for. All you can really say is that sometimes it is and sometimes it is not.

Comment: @YCor can you give reference to the proof of the fact that the condition holds if and only if the normal subgroup of G generated by $\{g^{-1}u(g) : g \in G\}$ is G itself?

Comment: @piper1967 I don't have a reference, but this seems to be a straightforward verification. In general, if $N$ is this normal subgroup, the quotient $K/\langle\!\langle h\rangle\!\rangle$ is naturally isomorphic to the finite group $G/N$.